# What is suitable for getting the total digits of a factorial of an integer? ceiling or floor?

Tags: numbers, factorial

Recently I solved a factorial problem in https://uva.onlinejudge.org. I solved it with the help of logarithm but still have a query that what is better to use to solve that kind of problem? `floor` or `ceil`?

I have a following C++ code below,

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int n,i;
    double sum;

    cin >> n;

    sum = 0;

    for (i=n; i>1; i--)
        sum += log10(i);

    cout << int (floor(sum)+1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In that code, I got the total digits of the factorial of an integer n. I updated the variable sum in each iterations using logarithm. But the fact is, when I take `cout << int (floor(sum)+1) << endl;`, that seems to be correct. But when I attempt to get the value by taking the ceiling of sum like that `cout << int ceil(sum) << endl;`, it seems to face an error for some numbers.

Now I am in a confusion when it happens? How can I find that numbers for whose the second statement gives wrong output?

Comment: Do you get errors when the factorial goes above n = 10?

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean I can not find error for any number yet. But the Judge Compiler shows it **Wrong Answer** all the time.

I heard, it gives wrong output for `10^x type` numbers, but I could not see the difference while checking with these type of numbers.